# How do I set up the Prometheus endpoints autodiscovery correctly in K8S?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I need to do endpoint autodiscovery in k8s cluster for prometheus scraping. Metrics in all services are
How should I do it properly? The metrics of all endpoints must be collected from uri /actuator/prometheus
I find out that I need to use kubernetes_sd_config, but I don't clearly understand what I should place in relabel_configs section in my case. Can you help me with this?

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'myapp'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
        namespaces:
          names:
            - dss
    relabel_configs:
...
```

I want prometheus scrape all metrics from all endpoint in namespace **dss**